# How to turn values into columns and columns into values at the same time in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the results of a ranked choice voting poll that provides the data in this format:

```
 choice_1   choice_2   choice_3   choice_4  
   <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>        
 1 Tuesday E… Thursday … Wednesday… Monday E…       
 2 Saturday … Saturday … NA         NA             
 3 Saturday … Tuesday E… Monday Ev… Wednesda…     
 4 Monday Ev… Tuesday E… Saturday … Sunday M…
```

I am trying to figure out a way to transform the data so it is structured like a ranked choice ballot actually would be, where the candidates are columns and the rankings are the values like so (not actual data):

```
| monday_evening | tuesday_evening | wednesday_evening |
| -------------- | --------------- | ----------------- |
|        1       |        3        |         2         |
|        2       |        1        |         NA        |
|        1       |        2        |         3         |
```

I know that `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` can be used to turn columns into values and turn values into columns respectively, but here I essentially need to do both at the same time and I'm totally lost as to if I can even make that happen.

**Solution**

I ended up using this to get the data formatted like a ballot would be:

```
x <- data %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("Choice"),
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(name = str_remove_all(name, "Choice ")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = name) %>% 
  select(-rn) %>% 
  mutate_all(as.integer)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if we need the suffix of column names a ranks, pivot to long format with `pivot_longer` and then reshape to wide after splitting the 'name' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(DescTools)
df1 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
   separate(name, into = c('name1', 'name2'), convert = TRUE) %>%
   select(-name1) %>%
   arrange(match(word(value, 1), day.name)) %>%
   mutate(rn = rowid(value)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = name2) %>%
   select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
#  `Monday Evening` `Tuesday Evening` `Wednesday Evening` `Thursday Evening` `Saturday Evening` `Sunday Morning`
#             <int>             <int>               <int>              <int>              <int>            <int>
#1                4                 1                   3                  2                  1                4
#2                3                 2                   4                 NA                  2               NA
#3                1                 2                  NA                 NA                  1               NA
#4               NA                NA                  NA                 NA                  3               NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(choice_1 = c("Tuesday Evening", "Saturday Evening", 
"Saturday Evening", "Monday Evening"), choice_2 = c("Thursday Evening", 
"Saturday Evening", "Tuesday Evening", "Tuesday Evening"),
choice_3 = c("Wednesday Evening", 
NA, "Monday Evening", "Saturday Evening"), choice_4 = c("Monday Evening", 
NA, "Wednesday Evening", "Sunday Morning")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: I realized this actually didn't do what I needed, since the choice numbers need to align with the original rows. I did figure it out though! From working off of the base of what you gave me so thank you.

Comment: Ah, I can understand. If I had given more data what I needed to do may have been clearer. The original data wouldn't have fit easily onto the width of a post so I abbreviated instead.

Comment: I think the main issue is that I tried to do an `arrange` which may not be needed.

Comment: @Abigail If you can show the expected output based on the data in my post.  it would be useful.  I can update the answer

Comment: Actually I think the only issue was that the row numbers needed to be associated with the original data. I didn't explain how ranked choice voting calculations work which could be part of the misunderstanding. It's not enough to know that X number of people ranked a given choice 1, 2, 3, etc. It matters the order each individual ranks the choices, so that if their 1st choice is eliminated their 2nd choice will be used in the next calculation round.

Comment: @Abigail As I said, if you can update your post with the expected based on the data in my post, it would be useful.  Otherwise, it is okay

Comment: @Abigail Your solution in the updated post is not really working for with this data.  It returns a list of columns `df1 %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('choice'), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%  mutate(name = str_remove_all(name, "choice_")) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = name)`  So it is not clear how it is working for you

Comment: I'm sorry I have no idea, I just know it does work for me. I've learned my lesson about using original data in posts.